# Convert text to 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

Im trying to fill a 2d-array with a text file.

My text file looks like this:

```
#######
# .# @#
#  #  #
#$##$##
#  #  #
#     #
#######
```

Its basicaly a level for a game. My final 2d-array shall look like this:

```
char [][] a = new char [6][6];

a[0][0] = #; a[0][1] = #; ... a[0][6] = #;
a[1][0] = #; a[1][1] =  ; a[1][2] = . ; ... a[1][6] = #;
.
.
.
a[6][0] = #;        . . .     a[6][6] = #;
```

My attempt is to read the rows in, convert them to 1d arrays and fill the 2d array with 2 loops. Then i need to print them out.

```
public class pp {

public static void main (String[] args) {

char [][]array2d = new char [6][7];

In.open("Level2.txt");

    while (In.done()){

        for (int rows=0; rows<7; rows++){

            String string = In.readLine();
            char [] array1d = string.toCharArray();

                for(int columns=0; columns<7;columns++){

                    array2d [rows][columns] = array1d [columns];
                    Out.print(array2d[rows][columns]);  

                    }                                       

            Out.println(); 

        }

    }

In.close();}}
```

Bizarrely it only prints everything out when i set the columns to 7

```
char [][]a = new char [6][7];
```

and the rows to 6

```
 for (int rows=0; rows<6; rows++){
```

I also become the error: 
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutofBoundException:0 at           pp.main(pp.java:18)

thats here

```
array2d [rows][columns] = array1d [columns];
```

And i am also not able to print the array2d out (code not shown). It simply does nothing when i try to get a[6][0] for example.

Im literally searching and trying for hours, i hope you can help me.

Comment: `rows` loops from `0` to `6` while the first array in `array2d` is of size `6` (meaning the last index is `5`). That's why you're getting the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: your 2d array needs to be declared with `[7][7]` since there are seven rows and column. It is not by the last number in the array but by the number of items so `[6][7]` would only be a 6*7 array which is too small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also dramatically reduce your code to not need so many for loops by realizing that when you call

```
In.readLine();
```

you are taking in a string which you correctly turn into a char array.  But you could set that directly into your array.  Which as the comments above have stated is not instantiated correctly.  You have 7 columns and 7 rows, thus you need

```
new char[7][7]
```

But when you call say the first element counting always STARTS AT 0.  So char[0][0] would output the first element

For example

```
public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    char[][] x = new char[7][7];
    char[] h = "Helpers".toCharArray();
    x[0] = h;
    for (char c : x[0]) System.out.println(c);
   }
}
```

So in this example I set my first row in my 2D array equal to an entire list.  So from here its pretty easy to find a full solution to your problem without having to use so many lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 [Streams](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java8/java8_streams.htm) make it really easy to create a two-dimensional character array from a text file.

```
char[][] array2d = Files.lines(file.toPath())
    .map(String::toCharArray)
    .toArray(char[][]::new);
```

One difference being your text file will determine the size of the two-dimensional character array.